# JavaScript - writing to a new document delets spaces

Tags: javascript

When I am writing to a new document:

```
    var pdf = "I'm Jhon \n Snow";
    var win = window.open();
    //css ltr
    win.document.write('<style>body { direction: ltr; unicode-bidi: bidi-override; }</style>');
    //insert txt
    win.document.write(pdf);
    win.print();
    win.close();
```

The output is in one line, without the `\n`, output - `I'm Jhon Snow` instead of

```
I'm Jhon

Snow
```

I am using regex to add the `\n` instead of `.` :

```
return textWithoutNewRow.replace(/([!.?])/g,'$1\n');
```

But the console shows the output with spaces.
fiddle - [complete code](https://jsfiddle.net/kck9be1s/2/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your newlines to be preserved in your rendered HTML output, you either have to replace them with `<br>` tags, or wrap your content in a `<pre>` tag.

You could update your regex as follows:

```
return textWithoutNewRow.replace(/([!.?])/g, '$1<br>');
```